# Is $\ell^3$ complete (as a metric space) as a subspace of $\ell^{3.14}$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

If you consider $\ell^3$ the usual metric on this set is given by $$d(x,y)=\left(\sum_j |\xi_j - \eta_j|^3 \right)^{1/3}$$ where $x = (\xi_j), y = (\eta_j) \in \ell^3$and it is known that $\ell^3$ is a complete metric space. Now if we induce the metric of $\ell^{3.14}$ on $\ell^3$ i.e., consider the set $\ell^3$ with the following metric $$d(x,y)=\left(\sum_j |\xi_j - \eta_j|^{3.14} \right)^{1/3.14}$$ will $\ell^3$ still remain a complete metric space?

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: $\ell^p$ will be a complete metric space as long as $p \geq 1$.

Comment: Yes, I know that $\ell^p$ will be complete metric space for all $p \geq 1$ with its usual metric. But if I induce another metric will it still remain complete? Can you explain why ?

Comment: If $Y$ is a dense proper subspace of a Banach space $X,$  then $Y$ cannot be complete.

Answer (score 1):

If $q>p$, then $(\ell^p,d_q)$ is not complete, as you can see by considering the sequence $f_n(k)=\begin{cases} k^c & k<n \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ where $cp \geq -1,cq<-1$.

Note that going the other way around is not possible, because you'd have some points that are infinitely far apart.